# Recursive algorithms and StackOverFlow Error

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I have been coding a recursive algorithm in order to go through different nodes and analyze all the paths in a directed acyclic graph. The thing is that, after some new data has been introduced to the algorithm I get this message `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError`. I have looked through different questions about this and it seems that the error is because of insufficient memory. Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Here I add a picture of the recursive algorithm:

```
public boolean checkduration(Node node, double dur, int freq){
    boolean outcome=true;
    currentPath.add(node);
    if((dur>minduration)&&(node.getRep()<=node.getMaxRep())){
        ArrayList<Node> clone = (ArrayList<Node>) currentPath.clone();
        currentPath2=clone;
        failingPaths.add(new ImmutableTriple<Double,Integer, ArrayList<Node>> (dur,freq,currentPath2)); 
        currentPath.remove(node);
        return false;
    }
    node.setRep(node.getRep()+1);

    for(int i=0;i<node.getEdge().size();i++){
        if(!checkduration(node.getEdge().get(i).previousNode,dur+node.getEdge().get(i).timeRelation, freq+node.getEdge().get(i).frequency)){
            outcome=false;  
        }
    }
    currentPath.remove(node);
    node.setRep(node.getRep()-1);
    return outcome;
 }
```

The error seems to be in the condition of `(if(!checkduration(node.getEdge().get(i).previousNode,dur+node.getEdge().get(i).timeRelation, freq+node.getEdge().get(i).frequency)))` but I do not understand why it works with some data and not always as not so much information has been changed.

Any comments, suggestions would be truly helpful. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StackOverflowError is occurring because you are recursing too many times. And if there are too many recursive calls, that means there is a flaw or incorrect assumption in your terminating condition. Here is your terminating condition:

```
(dur > minduration) && (node.getRep() <= node.getMaxRep())
```

Since you have not provided enough information with your question for us to analyze your graph or nodes further, I would suggest you take a closer look at this terminating condition, and make sure that every traversal of the graph will eventually fulfill this condition.

The use of the debugger can also help you to step through the traversal and see where the cycle is occurring, and why it fails to satisfy the terminal condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your graph traversal seems inefficient, since you are counting repetitions per each node, how many times you have visited and you limit your effort by adding some **maxRep**

All you need is the set of **visited nodes**, rather than increment of a counter for each node, when you visit it.

Does you DAG have many roots? Is the lack of cycles guaranteed, or do you need to detect cycles?

Please also note that you don't need cloning of paths.